# Newbie in prolog: Simple Solve

Tags: prolog

I am new to prolog, and I am trying to solve this:

It just returns false!

I have tried changing several parts of the code several times, as I said I'm a newbie in prolog and thus I don't know how to debug exactly..

```
livesIn(State):-
member(State,[california,georgia,delaware,iowa,kansas]).

sentGift(Gift):-
member(Gift,[rotisserie,salver,toaster,urn,vase]).

isHusband(Husband):-
member(Husband,[bill,doug,nick,tom,zack]).

solve(Z):-
Z=[[amber,Husband1,State1,Gift1],
   [emily,Husband2,State2,Gift2],
   [janet,Husband3,State3,Gift3],
   [maisie,Husband4,State4,Gift4],
   [patsy,Husband5,State5,Gift5]],

isHusband(Husband1), isHusband(Husband2), isHusband(Husband3), isHusband(Husband4), isHusband(Husband5),
Husband1 \== Husband2, Husband1 \== Husband3, Husband1 \== Husband4, Husband1 \== Husband5,
Husband2 \== Husband1, Husband2 \== Husband3, Husband2 \== Husband4, Husband2 \== Husband5,
Husband3 \== Husband1, Husband3 \== Husband2, Husband3 \== Husband4, Husband3 \== Husband5,
Husband4 \== Husband1, Husband4 \== Husband2, Husband4 \== Husband3, Husband4 \== Husband5,
Husband5 \== Husband1, Husband5 \== Husband2, Husband5 \== Husband3, Husband5 \== Husband4,

livesIn(State1), livesIn(State2), livesIn(State3), livesIn(State4), livesIn(State5),
State1 \== State2, State1 \== State3, State1 \== State4, State1 \== State5,
State2 \== State1, State2 \== State3, State2 \== State4, State2 \== State5,
State3 \== State1, State3 \== State2, State3 \== State4, State3 \== State5,
State4 \== State1, State4 \== State2, State4 \== State3, State4 \== State5,
State5 \== State1, State5 \== State2, State5 \== State3, State5 \== State4,

sentGift(Gift1), livesIn(Gift2), livesIn(Gift3), livesIn(Gift4), livesIn(Gift5),
Gift1 \== Gift2, Gift1 \== Gift3, Gift1 \== Gift4, Gift1 \== Gift5,
Gift2 \== Gift1, Gift2 \== Gift3, Gift2 \== Gift4, Gift2 \== Gift5,
Gift3 \== Gift1, Gift3 \== Gift2, Gift3 \== Gift4, Gift3 \== Gift5,
Gift4 \== Gift1, Gift4 \== Gift2, Gift4 \== Gift3, Gift4 \== Gift5,
Gift5 \== Gift1, Gift5 \== Gift2, Gift5 \== Gift3, Gift5 \== Gift4,

%Aunt Maisie's Husband is Uncle Nick
Husband4 = nick,

%Uncle Bill and Aunt Emily and their respective spouses sent the salver and the urn (in order)
Gift2 = salver,
member([_, bill, _, urn], Z),

%Aunt Amber and Uncle Doug live in Georgia
Husband1 = doug,
State1 = georgia,

%Aunt Patsy and her husband sent a toaster
Gift5 = toaster,

%The rotisserie came from the Delaware relatives
member([_, _, delaware, rotisserie], Z),

%Uncle Zack and his wife(don't live in Kansas) sent neither the salver nor the toaster
\+ member([_, zack, kansas, _], Z),
\+ member([_, zack, _, salver], Z),
\+ member([_, zack, _, toaster], Z),

%Aunt Janet and Uncle Bill live in California
Husband3 = bill,
State3 = california.
```

Comment: `livesIn(Gift2), livesIn(Gift3), livesIn(Gift4), livesIn(Gift5)` --> This looks fishy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Make it works

There are 2 typos in your code that prevents it from returning the correct result.

**First typo**

> Uncle Bill and Aunt Emily and their respective spouses sent the salver and the urn (in order)

So instead of:

```
Gift2 = salver,
member([_, bill, _, urn], Z),
```

It should be:

```
Gift2 = urn,                       % Aunt Emily sent the urn
member([_, bill, _, salver], Z),   % Uncle Bill sent the salver
```

**Second typo**

I don't know how you can make this typo! Why `livesIn` a gift?

```
sentGift(Gift1), livesIn(Gift2), livesIn(Gift3), livesIn(Gift4), livesIn(Gift5),
Gift1 \== Gift2, Gift1 \== Gift3, Gift1 \== Gift4, Gift1 \== Gift5,
```

Should be:

```
sentGift(Gift1), sentGift(Gift2), sentGift(Gift3), sentGift(Gift4), sentGift(Gift5),
Gift1 \== Gift2, Gift1 \== Gift3, Gift1 \== Gift4, Gift1 \== Gift5,
```

After fixing the 2 typos above, the code will work correctly, but it will take very long time to reach the solution.

### Make it fast

1. Order the direct unification with an atom (e.g. `Husband3 = bill`, `State1 = georgia`) **before** the membership unification of the `Gift`, `Husband` and `State` variables via `sentGift`, `isHusband` and `livesIn` predicates.

   Actually, you can just plug them directly to `Z`. And instead of declaring all those inequality manually (e.g. `Gift1 \== Gift2, Gift1 \== Gift3, Gift1 \== Gift4, Gift1 \== Gift5`), it is cleaner to write a predicate instead.
2. Order the membership unification (e.g. `member([_, bill, _, urn], Z)`) after the direct unification in part 1, but still before membership unification of the `Gift`, `Husband` and `State` variables.

   Note that this does **not** include `\+ member([_, zack, _, toaster], Z)`, which asserts that membership unification **CANNOT** succeed. Before the membership unification of the `Gift`, `Husband` and `State` variables which constraint them to a small set of possible values, it might be possible to find a unification that satisfy the membership unification, which leads to the clause and thus the whole predicate failing.

The 2 tricks above will reduce the search space and therefore reduce the time needed to find a solution. Below is some sample skeleton code for you to fill in when you have read the text above.

```
% Aunt Maisie's Husband is Uncle Nick
Husband4 = nick,

%% TODO: Fill in the rest on your own ...

% Uncle Bill and Aunt Emily and their respective spouses sent the salver and the urn (in order)
Gift2 = urn,




member([_, bill, _, salver], Z),

% The rotisserie came from the Delaware relatives
member([_, _, delaware, rotisserie], Z),




sentGift(Gift1), sentGift(Gift2), sentGift(Gift3), sentGift(Gift4), sentGift(Gift5),
Gift1 \== Gift2, Gift1 \== Gift3, Gift1 \== Gift4, Gift1 \== Gift5,
Gift2 \== Gift1, Gift2 \== Gift3, Gift2 \== Gift4, Gift2 \== Gift5,

%% TODO: Fill in the rest on your own





% Uncle Zack and his wife(don't live in Kansas) sent neither the salver nor the toaster
\+ member([_, zack, kansas, _], Z),
\+ member([_, zack, _, salver], Z),
\+ member([_, zack, _, toaster], Z).
```